# Memory allocation

Tags: c++, windows, managed-c++

I have the STRUCT1 Structure declared as below

```
typedef struct struct1 {
    short int nbr_fe;
    [size_is(nbr_fe)] STRUCT2  ptr_fe[*];
} STRUCT1;
```

STRUCT2 is also another structure inside STRUCT1

and then I have a pointer declared to it as below

```
typedef [ptr] STRUCT1 * ptr;
```

And I have to allocate a memory to an array of STRUCT1 base on the  nbrRequested 
And so far I have

```
STRUCT1 obj1;
memset((void*)&obj1, '\0' , sizeof(STRUCT1));

for(int i1=0;i1<(int)nbrRequested;i1++) {
   STRUCT2 obj2;
   memset((void*)&obj2, '\0' , sizeof(STRUCT2));
   obj1.ptr_fe[i1] = obj2;
}

ptr ptr2;
ptr2 = &obj1;
```

but if the nbrRequested is greater than 500, the loop goes in infinite and the application hangs.

Is there any better way to allocate a memory without using for loop

Comment: This reads more like C than C++. Are you sure you mean to claim this is C++?

Comment: It's not C. [size_is] is a MS Managed C++ extension.

Comment: Pete Kirkham: Thanks for that, I was wondering WTF I was looking at

Comment: It's not C++ either. The question is poorly written, poorly formatted and wrongly tagged. I'm outta here. Sorry.

Comment: This is C++ question 
I have formatted the code for more readability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allocating anything, you're overwriting the same data on the stack (which then goes out of scope when the loop exits.

In C++, you allocate memory with the new operator. In C you'd use malloc. So a minimal rewrite of your code would be something like this (in C, since that seems to be what you're writing)

```
// Allocate enough space for the array of `WF_LIST_WORKUNIT_P_FE`s
WF_LIST_WORKUNIT_P_FE listWU = malloc(sizeof(WF_STRUCT_WORKUNIT_FE) * nbrRequested);
memset(listWU, 0, sizeof(WF_STRUCT_WORKUNIT_FE) * nbrRequested));
```

Of course, this just sets every struct in the array to 0, rather than a more meaningful initialization, if that is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

This snippet should clear up that you need to malloc the memory, clear it, then you can assign the *pointer* to the structure member.

```
STRUCT1 listWU;
memset(&listWU, 0 , sizeof(STRUCT1));
for(int i1=0; i1<(int)nbrRequested; i1++) {
    STRUCT2 *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeoF(STRUCT2));
    memset(temp, 0 , sizeof(STRUCT2));
    listWU.lst_Workunit_fe[i1] = temp;
}
```

Oh, and don't forget when you're done with this structure, you need to free up all the pointers that were `malloc`'d in this structure or you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: Sorry I have formatted the structure declarations for better readability

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a C++ code

I would use new operator as below

**WF_LIST_WORKUNIT_P_FE *listWU = new WF_STRUCT_WORKUNIT_FE [nbrRequested + 1];**

The catch is structure  WF_STRUCT_WORKUNIT_FE itself is a nested structure of Structure WF_LIST_WORKUNIT_FE 
that is 
 typedef struct wf_list_workunit_fe
    {
        short int nbr_Workunits_fe;
        [size_is(nbr_Workunits_fe)] WF_STRUCT_WORKUNIT_FE  lst_Workunit_fe[*];
    } WF_LIST_WORKUNIT_FE;

wouldnt allocating a memory to WF_LIST_WORKUNIT_FE work ?